# Problems with MYSQL IN Function PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a little problem with my SQL query:

I have a variable ($arraySearch) with a string:

`$arraySearch = "'Bob', 'Ross'";`

My PHP query:

```
$stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `kunden` WHERE `FAMNAME` IN (arraySearch =:arraySearch) AND `VORNAME` IN (arraySearch = :arraySearch)");

$stmt->execute(['arraySearch' => $arraySearch]);

$all = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, $model);
```

Error Code:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function execute() on boolean
```

I've been searching for the error for hours but I can't find it.

What am I missing?

Does somebody have any idea?

best regards

Comment: $stmt->execute([$arraySearch]); or $stmt->execute(array('arraySearch' => $arraySearch));

Comment: you have a syntax error to start with ... `(arraySearch =:arraySearch)`

Comment: Since the array search is `'Bob', 'Ross'` ... is this really an error rather than a *happy little accident*?