# Problems with MYSQL IN Function PHP no data

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement, in-clause

my first Question was:

[Problems with MYSQL IN Function PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59565348/problems-with-mysql-in-function-php)

I got good answers and followed the link in my previous question.

[PHP - Using PDO with IN clause array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14767530/php-using-pdo-with-in-clause-array)

So i adapted my Code to this:

```
$in  = str_repeat('?,', count($arrWord) - 1) . '?';
$stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `kunden` WHERE FAMNAME IN ($in) AND VORNAME IN ($in)");
$stmt->execute($arrWord);
$all = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, $model);
```

but when i run the code the output from $all = array(0);

xdebug_output for $arrWord:

```
$arrWord = 
array(2)(
[0] => (string)Bob
[1] => (string)Ross
)
```

When i change the code to:

```
$in  = str_repeat('?,', count($arrWord) - 1) . '?';
$stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `kunden` WHERE FAMNAME IN ($in)");
$stmt->execute($arrWord);
$all = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, $model);
```

it works perfect and i got an output.

i tested my code with phpmyadmin and this was the output:

[image]

so my query is correct and I get output in phpmyadmin, but why not in php
anybody know what my problem is?

best regards

Comment: how many placeholders do you have in your query? and how many variables do you bind?

Comment: in the Query i have 4 place holders: "SELECT * FROM `kunden` WHERE FAMNAME IN (?,?) AND VORNAME IN (?,?)" and i have in my array 2 values: "Bob" and "Ross"

Comment: but you must always have the exact number of values. otherwise how mysq would know which values it has to bind?

Comment: You need to duplicate the parameters. Use `$stmt->execute(array_merge($arrWord, $arrWord));`

Comment: Ah now i understand, thank you very much :)